# Php код для внедрения hreflang на wordpress?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, можете помочь с php кодом, с помощью которого можно было бы внедрить разметку hreflang указав в ней нужные домены а страницы которых подбирались бы автоматически (url одинаковые за исключением домена), например:
есть сайт **site.ru** и **usa.site.ru** и нужен код который бы на каждой странице сайтов отображал ссылку как на русскую ее версию так и английскую.

Comment: вы не ошиблись ресурсом точно не http://fl.ru

Answer (score 1):

Есть множество различных плагинов, если правильно искать.
Если на одном сайте вести 2 версии, то есть q-translate и аналоги
https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/

Если же просто прописать уже существующие страницы, то HREFLANG Tags Lite или аналоги https://wordpress.org/plugins/hreflang-tags-by-dcgws/